# How to get response using Volley Library in android?

Tags: android, response, android-volley

I am using Volley Library for getting response from server.
Response get successfully earlier but now suddenly not getting response.

I don't know, What is the problem in my code?

My code is,

```
  public static void makeJsonData(final Activity activity, final String topic_id, final String user_id) {

        context = activity;
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(context);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        showpDialog();

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("topic_id", topic_id);
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            params.put("action", "getquestions");

            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!params======"+params);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Url.URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object
                    Boolean resultFlag = response.getBoolean("resultFlag");

                    if (resultFlag == true) {
                        String success = response.getString("successMessage");

                        JSONArray json_array_question = response.getJSONArray("Questions");

                        for (int i = 0; i < json_array_question.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject json_object_question = json_array_question.getJSONObject(i);

                            quiz_id = json_object_question.getInt("QuizID");
                            question_type = json_object_question.getString("questionType");
                            time_required = json_object_question.getString("timeRequired");

                        }

                    } else if (resultFlag == false) {
                        String error = response.getString("errorMessage");
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }


    private static void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private static void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

And Response is,

```
{
  "resultFlag": true,
  "successMessage": "Data Received",
  "Questions": [
    {
      "QuizID": 958,
      "questionType": "Trivia",
      "timeRequired": "10",
    }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error log ? if yes then please post here your log

Comment: @Vickyexpert in error log nothing display related response

Comment: Debug so you can see where's the problem.

Comment: @Vickyexpert when i am using degug point and do debug then not proceed  this line, JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Url.URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

Comment: Then try to debug your code step by step and check till which step you are able to get response and from which step it is not setting response

Comment: can you post your error log that might be much helpful in solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
// follow this sample code step by step
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView output ;
    String loginURL=""; // your URL
    String data = "";


    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            Log.d("STATE",savedInstanceState.toString());
        }

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
        JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try{

                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("posts");

                            for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                               JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                                // int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                                String url = jsonObject.getString("URL");

                               data += "Blog Number "+(i+1)+" \n Blog Name= "+title  +" \n URL= "+ url +" \n\n\n\n ";
                            }

                            output.setText(data);
                        }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley","Error");

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: And also use android.util.Log i.e Log to debug your code